# How to create page numbers (for navigation) on a web page

Tags: php, html

I am writing PHP script to display data from the database (Mysql) on my webpage. I don't want all the information to display on a single page to avoid scrolling. However, I want to display only a few and then use page numbers to navigate to the rest. I managed to create the page numbers and yet still all the information is showing on a single page. Below is my code:

```
<?php
    include('./includes/DB_Config.php');
    $status = 1;
    // Set number of Post per page for navigation                               
    $post_per_page = 2;
    if (isset($_GET['page']))
        {
            $startP = ($_GET['page'] - 1) * $post_per_page;
    }
    else
    {
        $startP = 0;
    }
    $post = mysqli_query ($mySQL_Conn, "SELECT * FROM BlogPost WHERE status = '$status'");
    // Fetch Data or number of rows
    $dataRw = mysqli_num_rows($post);   
    $pages = $dataRw /  $post_per_page;     
    if ($dataRw == 0)
    {
        $_SESSION['NoPost'] = "No Post Found!";
        }
    else
    {
        unset($_SESSION['NoPost']);
        //$pages = ceil($dataRw / $rows_per_page);  
        //$pages = array_slice($dataRw, $startP, $post_per_page);                       
        while ($data = mysqli_fetch_array($post)) //Fetch data in array
        {
            //Assign data to variabes       
            $name = $data['blogger_Name'];                      
            $postDate = $data['dateTime'];
            $blogpost = $data['blog_message'];
            $date = strtotime($postDate);
            ?>
            <p> <span><?php echo $_SESSION['NoPost'] ; ?> </span></p>
            <p> <span>By:</span><?php echo $name; ?> </p>
            <p> <span>Posted On: </span> <?php echo date("j F Y", $date); ?> </p>
            <p> <span>Post: </span><?php echo $blogpost; ?> </p>
            <?php
            }
    }
    ?>
    <hr>
    <?php
    for ($currentpage = 0; $currentpage < $pages; $currentpage++ )
    {
        ?>
            <span><a href="?page=<?php $currentpage + 1; ?>"> <?php echo $currentpage + 1; ?></a> </span> 
        <?php
    }
?>
```

Comment: So how are you getting the data from MySQL? It sounds like you're not putting any limits on the query

Comment: FYI: its called *pagination* googling that would probably help

Comment: You're mixing up PHP, HTML and SQL and assuming they are the same thing or thinking that people should assume you are using them.

Comment: Or, you can use this pagination script in your project, [https://github.com/rajdeeppaul/Pagination](https://github.com/rajdeeppaul/Pagination). The usage documentation is pretty simple and straight forward.

Answer (score 0):

What you are trying to accomplish is a very common pattern, and it's called pagination.

You can use `LIMIT` and `OFFSET` in your mysql queries to get only a certain subset of the data, and you can use this for basic pagination.

For example, if you want to display 50 results per page, and the user is on the third page, you set `LIMIT` to 50 and `OFFSET` to 2*50 (100), keep in mind the first page is an offset of 0 so we subtract the page by one.

You can use the following sql query to get a subset of data for a specific page.

```
"SELECT * FROM Users LIMIT $num_results OFFSET ".(($page_num-1)*$num_results);
```

You can get the total number of possible pages by getting the total row count from the Users table and dividing it by $num_results. A good idea might be to have your output script take a `GET` url query parameter that will be used as the page number.